# Import error in superset installation process

Tags: flask, installation, import, apache-superset, werkzeug

Getting this error:  from werkzeug.urls import Href
ImportError: cannot import name 'Href' from 'werkzeug.urls'  . while running superset db upgrade on Windows.

Flask version: 2.1.3
Werkzeug version: 2.2.1
pytest version: 7.4.3
Python version: 3.10.0

How to resolve this issue? Getting some other errors regarding import too

Tried compatible versions of Flask and Werkzeug .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.